# How to send data entered in the extension menu to another file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension, I made a menu to it in which the user enters some data. It is necessary to make so that on a click on the button (in the menu of expansion) these data.

Here is how it must works: `background.js` is the file that is responsible for js in the extension menu.  `content.js` is the file that is responsible for making changes to the DOM on the sites.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
  //sending in content.js
  chrome.extension.sendMessage('hello');
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="text" id="second">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="send">
```

`content.js` Getting data:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
    if(request=='hello'){
        console.log('1. Get: ', request);
    }
});
```

But from `background.js` i get nothing.

Here is `manifest.json`

```
{

 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "1.3",
 "description": "name",
 "browser_action":{
    "default_popup": "content/popup.html"
 },
     "background": {
     "persistent": false,
         "scripts": ["content/background.js"]
        },
      "content_scripts": [
          {
             "matches": [ "https://google.com/*" ],
             "js": ["content/content.js"],
             "css": ["content/qq.css"],
             "run_at": "document_end"
         }
     ]
 }
```

It turns out that I need to send the entered data in the field with the button `send` to a file that will insert this data into the page I need. How to do it?
Help, because if I put the code that it does in my `js` file, then it tries to take this data from`input` on the page, and not from the extension menu.

Here is the structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita i update my question.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990609/3930351) to your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there seems to be a couple of n00b issues here:

- `background.js` is a script that runs in the background *of all tabs/pages*. (The "background" section in the `manifest.json` specifies this).
  PS: The way to debug the `background.js` is to open chrome's extension page (`chrome://extensions/`) and click on "Inspect Views: background page" from there. Typically, this is where most of your code would be.
- `content.js` will automatically be inserted into all `google.com` pages, according to your manifest.
- `popup.html` and it's code only exists as long as the popup is visible. It's typically very light, with little code. So, in your `popup.html`, remove the two existing `<script>` entries you have, and just use a single script, (typically popup.js):

  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
- When sending info from the popup (or background) to the current tab (in your case it's going to be `google.com` only) you use the general code:

  ```
  // Get the current tab & tell it to do something
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var currentTab = tabs[0];
      var id = currentTab.id;
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id,
              { action: 'foo', data:... }, 
              response => { console.log('some response from content.js is:' + response); });

  });
  ```

  but to send a message to the background (from a page or your content script inside google.com), you'd just use this `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:'foo', data:...});`

So, your code should probably be something like:

**popup.html**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>...
```

**popup.js:**

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
  //sending in content.js
  var foo_data="I am foo";

    // Get the current tab & tell it to do something
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var currentTab = tabs[0];
        var id = currentTab.id;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id,
                { action: 'hello', foo:foo_data, first:first, second:second }, 
                response => { console.log(response); });

    });

}
```

**background.js**

(nothing)

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.action=='hello'){
        console.log(request.foo + ' ' request.first + ' '  + request.second);
        sendResponse('I got foo!');
    }
});
```

If it's any help, I've a tiny project that I use to get started on webextension projects here: https://github.com/cmroanirgo/webextension-template. It's got some code to help with making it work cross browser (Firefox, Opera & maybe Edge)

I hope this helps.

Comment: `ext.tabs.sendMessage` is undefined. There is no element with id `first` or `second` in your `popup.html`. This code will send the message to the active tab, which is not necessarily the one with the content script.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko. Sorry about that, I'd copied the code from other working code, which has a cross-browser library. The popup.html is just a clarification of what should be in the head. All the code is just demonstration code, based off the original question, and obviously may not work in a copy-paste scenario. Also, you've made assumptions about the google.com content script. There may be multiple, there may not be -- it's too hard to tell.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko. Also, using the 'active tab' method is less confusing if there are multiple google.com pages open. This way, if the current tab is google.com, the popup works, if it doesn't, then it does nothing -- it's much easier for an end user.

Comment: What assumptions? The OP wants their code to work on google.com pages whether they are active/visible or not.

Comment: it's ok, thx. But if u can, tell me please: i enter some value in input(popup.html), after that i get this value in popup.js and send it in content.js. In content.js i do some changes in DOM of google.com,  but after updating page all changes are gone. How can i fix it?So, i need save change in DOM of some site even if i reload page

Comment: @МаксимБуяков. You should start a new question, as it is different from this one, even though it's part of the same project. Basically, you need to rethink your strategy and what you're trying to accomplish. Search google for 'MDN webextension examples' to give you ideas.