# "Communicate" the contents js and background js files in extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension and I encountered a problem: I can not send data from the extension menu to `content.js`. In the extension menu I have a couple of intuitions, after filling in and clicking on the button, I write down their values and I want to send them to `content.js` where this data will be used for implementation in`html` But for some reason, the data is not sent.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
  //send in content
  chrome.extension.sendMessage('hello');
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="text" id="second">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="send">
```

Here is the `manifest.json` (maybe there's something wrong)

```
{

 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "1.3",
 "description": "name",
 "browser_action":{
    "default_popup": "content/popup.html"
 },
     "background": {
     "persistent": false,
         "scripts": ["content/background.js"]
        },
      "content_scripts": [
          {
             "matches": [ "https://google.com/*" ],
             "js": ["content/content.js"],
             "css": ["content/qq.css"],
             "run_at": "document_end"
         }
     ]
 }
```

`content.js`: get data from background

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
    if(request=='hello'){
        console.log('1. Принято: ', request);
    }
});
```

As I can see everything, `background.js` is the file that is responsible for`js` in the extension menu. `content.js` is the file that is responsible for making changes to the DOM on the sites.

Answer (score 3):

Your files' structure is unclear: what is the content of `popup.html`? why do you load both `content.js` and `background.js` in the same page?

Here is an example that does what ***I think*** you try to accomplish.

It works like this:

The popup screen will display the `input`s for the user to fill.
When the button is pressed, the value of the inputs is sent to the background script which, in turn, sends them to the content script. The content script then uses those values in the way you want: for instance, to fill an input in the host webpage.

**manifest.json**

```
{

 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "1.3",
 "description": "name",
 "browser_action":{
    "default_popup": "content/popup.html"
 },
 "background": {
     "persistent": true,
     "scripts": ["content/background.js"]
 },
 "content_scripts": [
     {
         "matches": [ "https://google.com/*" ],
         "js": ["content/content.js"],
         "css": ["content/qq.css"],
         "run_at": "document_end"
     }
 ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
var contentTabId;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg,sender) {
  if (msg.from == "content") {  //get content scripts tab id
    contentTabId = sender.tab.id;
  }
  if (msg.from == "popup" && contentTabId) {  //got message from popup
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(contentTabId, {  //send it to content script
      from: "background",
      first: msg.first,
      second: msg.second
    });
  }
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:"content"}); //first, tell the background page that this is the tab that wants to receive the messages.

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  if (msg.from == "background") {
    var first = msg.first;
    var second = msg.second;
    //here you use the values as you wish, for example:
    //document.getElementById("anInput").value = first;
  }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="first">
    <input type="text" id="second">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js** (this file must be located in the same directory as `popup.html`)

```
document.getElementById("send").onclick = function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({  //send a message to the background script
    from: "popup",
    first: document.getElementById("first").value,
    second: document.getElementById("second").value
  });
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `runtime` property of the chrome / browser object.

This would make your send message command `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` without the use of the `extension` property.

Likewise the on message event would be `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.

I'm pulling this info from the following documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

Comment: can u can example please?

Comment: The Mozilla site has some good examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage

Answer (score 1):

`content.js` should not be included into `popup.html`. `content.js` is run whenever a site matches the pattern in your `manifest.json`. Right now, whenever someone visits google.com with your extension installed, the `content.js` script is run in the background of google.com.

`background.js` also shouldn't be loaded into the popup. It's a script that's always run in the background of the browser, it's not something that should get loaded by anything. It's where you add stuff like code to change the omnibox behavior.

You should create a new `popup.js` script that gets included by `popup.html`, and it should only handle things like onload and onclick events for the actual popup window.

The various files you mention, `content.js`, `background.js` and the file you should create `popup.js` all have different jobs and should not communicate between each other. There's neither a need nor a possibility for it. If you want to e.g. get the value of what's inside some other site put it in `content.js`, which is run on each site that matches your pattern, and do all the handling in there.

`background.js` = code that sets up your extension inside the browser, stuff like changing the omnibox behavior.

`content.js` = code that runs on each website that matches a certain pattern.

`popup.js` = code that runs when the user opens the popup window of your extension.

So don't have them communicate, they aren't supposed to, they fill entirely different functions.

There's no reason why you should need to communicate between them either, please explain a scenario where you'd need this and I'll explain why you don't need it. :)

Comment: okay, look: in my `popup.html` i have some input and button. When i type smth in input and click on button value from input should be value of some DOM element on google.com

Comment: The [Chrome extension architecture documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) mentions messaging as a method to communicate between the different elements of the extension; and you have API methods such as `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` for that purpose. The best way to communicate from popup page to content script is through messaging.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with `content.js`, you need to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.extension.sendMessage`, because to communicate with the `content.js` you need to provide the **tabId**, which is passed as an argument in the former listed API.

Comment: in background.js we call chrome.tabs.sendMessage and then content.js received that. But what about if content.js want to send back to background.js ?